# Any way to generate POJOs of a database?

Tags: java, code-generation

is there anyway to generate POJOs from selected tables of a database? I'm working on a jsf/primefaces/mybatis project which has at least 40 tables and it's really time consuming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally IDEs contains tools for that purpose. For example, in Eclipse: http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jpt.doc.user%2Ftasks021.htm

Here for JDeveloper:
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18941_01/tutorials/jdtut_11r2_11/jdtut_11r2_11.html

Answer (score 4):

You can do that (and more) with **Telosys** a simple code generator 
that uses the database schema to generate any kind of source file (POJO, Services, Spring MVC, etc)

See  http://www.telosys.org